# How to retrieve the values from a 2-D array in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

```
B = [150 90; -100 -120; -80 130; 140 -70; 60 120; -90 -130];
```

These are the values of 6 co ordinates. I want to calculate the average distance from these co ordinates. I need to use this function. But I cannot assign the 2nd value from each co ordinate in the function.

```
davg = 0;
m = 0;
c=0.707;
B=[150 90; -100 -120; -80 130; 140 -70; 60 120; -90 -130];

for j = 1:6
    for i = 1:2
        m =m+((sqrt(B(j,i)^2+B(j,i+1)^2))/c);
    end
end
davg = m/6;
```

Comment: It can be done without for loop: `davg = mean(sqrt(B(:,1).^2+B(:,2).^2)/c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already calculate the sum of the squared elements, you don't need the inner loop. For the 2-dimensional case, you could just write:

```
m = m + ((sqrt(B(j, 1).^2 + B(j, 2).^2)) / c);
```

For the n-dimensional case, you could re-write the loop in the following way:

```matlab
% Input and parameters.
davg = 0;
m = 0;
c = 0.707;
B = [150 90; -100 -120; -80 130; 140 -70; 60 120; -90 -130];

% Get number of data points and dimensionality.
nPoints = size(B, 1);
nDim = size(B, 2);

% Iterate every data point.
for j = 1:nPoints

  % Calculate sum of squared elements in loop (for arbitrary dimensionality).
  temp = 0;
  for i = 1:nDim
      temp = temp + B(j, i).^2;
  end

  % Apply square root afterwards.  
  m = m + sqrt(temp) / c;

end

% Calculate average.
davg = m / nPoints
```

I'm aware, that you wrote, that you have to use the mentioned formula, nevertheless, the whole calculation can be simplified to:

```matlab
% Input and parameters.
c = 0.707;
B = [150 90; -100 -120; -80 130; 140 -70; 60 120; -90 -130];

% Calculate average.
davg = mean(vecnorm(B, 2, 2) / c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Weighted dum of all vectors should be fine?

```
sum(sqrt(sum(B.^2,2)))/size(B,1)
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, your answer is wrong. Where do you consider the squares and square root?

Comment: Gotcha just a sec. The above what you want?